# Problemas con AJAX, JQUERY y JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Soy nuevo con AJAX y tengo varios problemas. En este momento, cuento con un código para enviar datos de un formulario por JQuery y con estos, generar una consulta en la misma página.

Este es el código del HTML (aunque lo tengo como .PHP):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Control de Ingresos y Salidas del Centro.</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilos/consultaraprendices.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function obtener_datos(){
                $.ajax({                        
                    type:'POST',                 
                    url:"consultaprendiz.php",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#consulta').html(data);       
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).on("click", "#enviar", function(){
                var documento=document.getElementById("documento").value;
                alert(doc);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"consultaprendiz.php",
                    data: {documento:"1070627714"},
                    success: function(data){
                        obtener_datos();
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#enviar", function(){
                var tipodoc=document.getElementById('tipodoc').value;
                alert(tipodoc);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'REQUEST',
                    url:"consultaprendiz.php",
                    data:{tipodoc:"2"},
                    success: function(data){
                        obtener_datos();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <select name="tipodoc" id="tipodoc">
            <option value="0">Tipo de documento</option>
            <option value="1">Tarjeta de identidad</option>
            <option value="2">C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</option>
            <option value="3">C&eacute;dula de extranjer&iacute;a</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="documento" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de documento" id="documento" required>
        <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Consultar</button>
    <section id="consulta">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este, es la página que me debería hacer la consulta:

```
    <?php
include('conexion.php');
$doc=$_POST['documento'];
$tipodoc=$_REQUEST['tipodoc'];
?>
<?php
        if ($tipodoc==1) { 
            $a = "SELECT * FROM aprendices, fichas, jornadas, ambientes WHERE aprendices.tipo_doc_ap='T.I.' AND aprendices.doc_ap='$doc' AND aprendices.id_ficha=fichas.id_ficha AND fichas.id_jornada=jornadas.id_jornada AND fichas.num_ambiente=ambientes.num_ambiente";
            $b = mysqli_query($mysqli, $a);
            while ($z=mysqli_fetch_array($b)){
                echo "<img src='../imagenes/boton.png' id='foto'>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='nombre'>" . $z['nombres_ap']; echo " " . $z['apellidos_ap'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='ficha'>" . $z['id_ficha'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='programa'>" . $z['nombre_ficha'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='jornada'>" . $z['nombre_jornada'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='ambientes'>" . $z['num_ambiente']; echo " - " . $z['dependencia_ambiente'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='celular'>" . $z['celular_ap'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='estadogeneral'>" . $z['estado_ap'] . "</font>"; echo "<font size='10' class='cajas' id='correo'>" . $z['correo_ap'] . "</font>";
            }
        }
```

Agradecería la ayuda, porque he intentado varias cosas, pero siempre me aparece el error de índices indefinidos.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Lo primero que es muy extraño es que tengas varias peticiones Ajax ... ¿A qué se debe eso?  Otra cosa que debe quedar claro es que si envías el `data` así por ejemplo: `data: {documento:"1070627714"}` en el `POST` o `GET` debes buscar por la clave `documento`, algo así: `$_POST['documento']`, pues se busca el índice que se pone a la izquierda de `data`. Los undefined index son sin duda por el lío de peticiones Ajax que tienes. Deja una sola, bien escrita y prueba. En PHP no mezcles `REQUEST` y `POST`. Si el tipo de petición es `POST` entonces usa `POST`

Comment: De verdad, muchas gracias. Ya lo intenté, pero sigue sin funcionarme. Los índices siguen sin definirse. Lo que se me hace más extraño, es que un código, bastante similar, lo utilizo en otra sección de la página y me funciona perfectamente. Realmente no entiendo porqué para enviar ese tipo de datos y realizar una consulta, AJAX no me envía los datos.

Comment: Edita la pregunta dejando el código como lo tienes actualmente. Repito, es muy extraño que tengas tantas peticiones Ajax. Deja una sola para ir depurando hasta encontrar el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya depuré bastante el código. Quiero aclarar que tengo una página principal. Ahí quiero hacer todo sin llevarme a ninguna otra página externa. He intentado varios códigos, pero no funciona el AJAX cuando se llamó una página dentro de la principal. Aún así, el AJAX que necesito realizar en este momento, es para realizar una consulta y que me muestre la misma consulta en la misma página.

La página de ejemplo se llama: consultarfuncionarios.php

```
    <?php
include('conexion.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Control de Ingresos y Salidas del Centro.</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           function obtener_datos(){
                $.ajax({                        
                    type:"POST",                 
                    url:"consultarfuncionarios.php",
                    success: function(data){ 
                    }
                });
            };
            $(document).on("click", "#enviar", function(){
                var documento=$("#document").val();
                alert(documento);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"consultarfuncionarios.php",
                    data:{documento:documento},
                    success: function(data){
                        obtener_datos();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <font id="mensaje">N&uacute;mero de documento:&nbsp;</font>
        <input type="number" name="document" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de documento" id="document">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">Consultar</button>
    <section id="consulta">
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['document'])) {
            $doc=$_POST['document'];
            $a = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios, ambientes WHERE funcionarios.cc_funcionario='$doc' AND funcionarios.num_ambiente=ambientes.num_ambiente ";
            $b = mysqli_query($mysqli, $a);
            while ($z=mysqli_fetch_array($b)){
                echo "<img src='../imagenes/boton.png' id='foto'>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='nombre'>" . $z['nombres_f'] . " "; 
                echo $z['apelidos_f'] . "</font>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='cargo'>" . $z['cargo_funcionario'] . "</font>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='ambientes'>" . $z['num_ambiente']; 
                echo " - " . $z['dependencia_ambiente'] . "</font>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='celular'>" . $z['celular_f'] . "</font>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='estadogeneral'>" . $z['estado_funcionario'] . "</font>"; 
                echo "<font class='cajas' id='correo'>" . $z['correo_f'] . "</font>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <section id="novedades"></section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Por cierto, cuando utilizo sólo el  (sin código JS) me sale perfecto en la sección de abajo, pero me dirige a otra página para mostrarme la consulta.

Además, la variable sí se me define y parece que se envía, pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: ¿Es esto una solución a la pregunta o más información para la misma? Parece más lo segundo, en cuyo caso deberías editar la pregunta para añadir esta nueva información. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información.

Comment: Sí, es una pregunta. Intento mostrar el código que utilizo, pero que sigue sin funcionarme.